# inline methods not available as symbols of shared library

Tags: c++, reference, linker, inline, undefined

If I have a class which will be compiled to a shared object.
The class is declared in a .h file and implemented in a .cpp file.

This class contains a couple of **inline methods**.

If I write some program that links with this shared library and includes the .h file,
I will get *undefined reference* errors when linking it.

Is that because there are no symbols exported for inline methods ?

Am I understanding this correctly ?

**UPDATE:** some example code below

somelib.h

```
#ifndef __ABC_LIB_H
#define __ABC_LIB_H
#include <iostream>
class ABC {
    ABC();
    ~ABC();
    inline void not_callable_outside_library();
    void callable_outside_library();
};
#endif
```

somelib.cpp

```
#include "somelib.h"
ABC::ABC() {}
ABC::~ABC() {}
void ABC::not_callable_outside_library(){ std::cout<<"not_callable_outside_library"<<std::endl; }
void ABC::callable_outside_library(){ std::cout<<"callable_outside_library"<<std::endl; }
```

program.cpp

```
#include "somelib.h"
int main() {
    ABC x;
    x.not_callable_outside_library();
    return 0;
};
```

Compile somelib.cpp as a shared library( .so object) and link it program.cpp then you get the binary called **program**.

Now you should get an **undefined reference** when linking.

Comment: It shouldn't need any symbols for inline methods. Show us some code & the errors.

Comment: You are correct that inline functions do not provide external definitions for linking. As for your error, you should structure your class definition so that you aren't directly dependent on the inline functions outside of the shared object.

Comment: LuchianGrigore see above ;   @chrisaycock thanks for confirming. thumbs up !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline functions must be defined in header files. Contrast what you have to the following:

somelib.h:

```
#ifndef ABC_LIB_H
#define ABC_LIB_H

#include <iostream>
class ABC {
    ABC();
    ~ABC();
    void not_callable_outside_library();
    void callable_outside_library();
};

inline void ABC::not_callable_outside_library() {
    std::cout << "not_callable_outside_library\n";
}

#endif
```

somelib.cpp:

```
#include "somelib.h"

ABC::ABC() { }
ABC::~ABC() { }
void ABC::callable_outside_library() {
    std::cout << "callable_outside_library\n";
}
```

program.cpp:

```
#include "somelib.h"

int main() {
    ABC x;
    x.not_callable_outside_library();
}
```